# Funciones de scope en Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, scope, extensiones

Estoy viendo las funciones de scope en Kotlin (let, run, with, apply, also) y tengo una duda entre apply y with. He leido que se usa apply cuando el valor necesita retornarse a si mismo, pero ¿que quiere decir esto? Ya que viendo los códigos es casi lo mismo:

```
val mediaItem = MediaItem("Title 14", "", MediaItem.Type.PHOTO).apply {
    title = "Title 15"
    imageUrl = ""
    typeElement = MediaItem.Type.VIDEO
}

with(mediaItem) {
    title = "Title 16"
    imageUrl = ""
    typeElement = MediaItem.Type.VIDEO
}
```

Lo unico que veo es que with necesita el objeto para ser usado y con apply lo usamos a partir de este objeto, pero no me termina de quedar muy claro, a ver si alguno de vosotros me lo podéis explicar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Efecivamente son muy similares, las principales diferencias son:

- `with` no necesita un objeto sobre el que ser llamado, mientras que `apply` si.
- `apply` se ejecuta en la referencia del objeto, mientras que `with` lo pasa como un argumento.
- La ultima expresión de `with` devuelve un restultado.